# How do boxwing and tandem airplanes balance moment

Tags: stability, canard, flying-wing

I want to build a hydrofoil like this picture:
[image]

I discovered that you can pump it with a leg motion and moving the center of mass.
Like this:

I discovered xflr5 and did some of my own simulation. I am in aww of the complexity of aeronautic engineering. I learned so much in such a small time.

As you can see in the video, pumping is very hard and you can only do it for short amount of times. so that i had the idea to optimize the wing configuration for this type of drive. I am not quite sure if the rear wing produces lift or is actually pushing down like in a commercial aircraft. My design in xflr5 has a very high aspect ration and a very high wingspan and i am searching for designs with higher aerodynamic efficiency.

I found a few ideas:

1. Flying wings i guess it would be hard to get longitudinal stability if the center of mass is so high.
2. A canard wing configuration.
3. Flying wing with bell shaped lift distribution
4. Boxwing configuration
5. Tandem configuration.

But i dont understand how tailless boxwing configuration produce longitudinal stability same for tandem configuration.